# "Leave me message as you get free" Is this sentence grammatically wrong?

Tags: word-choice

it sounds weird to me when my friend texted me "***Leave me message as you get free***" because I always say "***you're free***".

I hope to get second answer instead of the answer from [Speaking English - Bravenet.com.](http://pub31.bravenet.com/faq/show.php?catid=6117&usernum=2591745937) Thanks.

> 129. "Call me when you will get free." Is this a correct sentence?
>
> No. "Call me when you're free." = Call me when you have time. "Call me
>   when you get free." = Call me when you are out of prison (or some
>   other type of confinement). That one word "get" changes the whole
>   meaning of the sentence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Leave me a message as you get free.

I would write that as:

> Leave me a message **when** you **are** free.

If you use "as" instead of "when", it implies that you are asking someone to do two things at the same time. Using "get free" instead of "are free" is also a problem, because it can sound like you're talking to someone who is escaping from imprisonment, instead of someone who is busy.

Example that uses "get free"

> Houdini, call me **when** you get free from that straitjacket.

Example that uses "as you"

> Call me as you walk home.

Your original sentence could be rewritten as a little joke that makes finishing whatever task is keeping your friend busy the same as escaping from some type of imprisonment:

> Leave me a message as **soon as** you get free from Sir Talks-a-lot.

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure if I can ask about this. My friend learned **as you get free** from her non-native teacher. My friend and I are English learners. We discussed about *as you get free** before posting my question on ELL. Actually she had same thoughts as me when her teacher taught her **as you get free**. After I told her about your answer, she asked her teacher intentionally : As you get free = when you're free? Do they have same meaning? _PART 1_

Comment: Her teacher's answer: They have a little difference, for example: You will be free at 8 o'clock. _I told you as you get free leave me message._ It means that you should leave me message exactly at 8. _But leave me message when you are free_ means you can message me after 8. What do you think about her teacher's answer? I'm sorry if I'm not allowed not ask..

Comment: @puputeh24 I can see the teacher's point, but "as you get free" isn't common in my area and would sound strange to me. If I wanted you to call me the moment you were free, I would say "as soon as you are free", as I did in the last example. And it's OK to discuss answers in the comments - that's what they're supposed to be used for :)